# Making a time delay in Pygame based on FPS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Every single tutorial or answer I see about making a time delay is based on pygame ticks, which means that the delay will never be exactly the length you want it to be (not to mention half the time I'm not even sure how the code actually delays anything). What would be a good way to make something not happen until a certain amount of time has passed, but based on how many frames have passed rather than milliseconds?

Just an extra note since this was marked as a duplicate- the question this was a "duplicate" of was asking about using pygame ticks, this about timing based on frames rather than milliseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a counter in your main while loop that increments every iteration, and have an `if` that makes something happen if the counter exceeds a certain number, something like:

```
ctr = 0
frames = 100
while True:
    if ctr >= frames:
        make_something_happen()
    ctr += 1
    handle_pygame_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to return the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. Calculate the point in time after something has to happen. Do somthong after the current time is greater than the calculated point of time:

```py
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
start_time = current_time + delay_time

run = True
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # [...]

    if current_time >= start_time :
        # do something
        # [...]

    # [...]
```

If you don't want to use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` you need to summarize the time for each frame. However FPS are inaccurate. Even if you use [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) the FPS will be inaccurate and you will need to get the delta time for each frame from `tick()`:

> This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call.

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
passed_time = 0

while True:
    passed_time += clock.tick(100)

    # [...]

    if passed_time > delay_time:
        # do something
        # [...]
```

Comment: If you read the post, you would see that this is the specific thing I was trying to avoid

Comment: @NiallStrain I see. However the [tag:pygame-clock] tag is misleading. I've deleted it.

Comment: @NiallStrain Why do you try to avoid this? This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Because I wanted the timing to be more accurate by using FPS, not the time since pygame started. I already know how to do timing using ticks, and the answer above answered how to use frames instead.

Comment: @NiallStrain *"I wanted the timing to be more accurate by using FPS"* but FPS are inaccurate. The above answer does not take into account that the time for a frame can be different for each frame. Even if you use `pygame.time.Clock.tick()` the FPS are inaccurate and you have to get the delta time for each frame from `tick()`. The most accurate way is to measure the time with `pygame.time.get_ticks()`.